KL Markov chain mixing result
Suppose $P$ is the transition matrix of a Markov chain with stationary distribution $\pi$. I am wondering what results can be said about how $P$ mixes distributions under the KL divergence? In particular, whether there exist results in the following forms, for probability vectors $\mu$ and $\nu$:
$$ \mathop{KL}(\pi\,||\,P\mu) \leq \alpha\mathop{KL}(\pi\,||\,\mu), \tag{1}$$
$$ \mathop{KL}(P\nu\,||\,P\mu) \leq \alpha\mathop{KL}(\nu\,||\,\mu). \tag{2}$$
Further, if $\mu\ne \pi$ and $\nu\ne \pi$ can either of the inequalities be made strict? Feel free to make any necessary assumptions on $P$.
